# "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes" error

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning how to make web pages with AngularJS (in fact, I have the exam tomorrow), and I have a problem.

I used codeCademy as the learning course, but my exam allows external (printed) files to help you, so I made the exercises offline on my computer too.

The first chapter, (no directives, just setting up your app and using controllers) is no problem. The server from ajax googleapis for angularJS is working perfect. So three weeks ago, I finished the course (always using the server from ajax googleapis), and everything worked fluently.

Today, I'm just remaking the exercises, and when I'm making the first exercise from Directives, I'm getting a bunch of errors (these exercises worked perfectly 3 weeks ago). When I'm loading the old exercises I made 3 weeks ago, they don't work either.

So I'm not getting why these errors show up now, and not 3 weeks ago.

The code:
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="BoltNetworkApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <img src="img/logo.svg" width="180" height="34">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3" class="series_img">
              <img ng-src="{{ program.series_img }}">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h1 class="series">{{ program.series }}</h1>
              <h2 class="episode">{{ program.episode }}</h2>
              <p class="description">{{ program.description }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item"><span>Date:</span>{{ program.datetime | date:'mediumDate' }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><span>On air:</span>{{ program.datetime | date:'EEEE' }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><span>Time:</span>{{ program.datetime | date:'shortTime' }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><span>Season:</span>{{ program.season }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><span>Genre:</span>{{ program.genre }}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>Bolt</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Careers</li>
              <li>Terms</li>
              <li>Help</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>More Bolt</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Gift Cards</li>
              <li>Trailers</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>News</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Blog</li>
              <li>Twitter</li>
              <li>YouTube</li>
              <li>Google+</li>
              <li>Facebook</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think there something changed with the ajax servers online, because this worked perfect 3 weeks ago.

Does anyone has a solution for this (please don't say local webserver, because it worked just fine with a server online, I wanna know how to fix this with the online server).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it. For some (dumb) reason I don't know, this doesn't work in Chrome. I loaded it in Firefox and it works perfectly.